# Testing a react-query hook that uploads a binary file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-query

There is a unit test that's failing on the following react-query hook.
The hook works fine otherwise, it uploads a binary file to an endpoint.

Here is the hook:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';

import { IUploadFieldRequest } from '../constants/types';
import { licenseServiceAPI } from '../services';

export const URI = () => '/licenses/upload';

export const useUploadLicense = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [apiService] = licenseServiceAPI<IUploadFieldRequest>({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  });

  const {
    data: response,
    mutateAsync,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  } = useMutation(
    (formData: IUploadFieldRequest) => {
      const form = new FormData();
      Array.from(formData.files)?.forEach((file) => {
        form.append('license-file', file);
      });

      return apiService.post(URI(), form);
    },
    {
      onError: () => {
        return queryClient.invalidateQueries('licenseUpload');
      }
    }
  );

  return {
    data: response?.data,
    uploadFiles: mutateAsync,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  };
};

export default useUploadLicense;
```

And this is the test for it:

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

import { queryClientInstance } from '@oam/shared/test-utils';

import useUploadLicense from './use-upload-license';

const file = new File(['file'], 'license-file.json', { type: 'multipart/form-data' });

it('upload files', async () => {
  const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useUploadLicense(), {
    wrapper: queryClientInstance
  });

  act(() => {
    result.current.uploadFiles({ files: [file] });
  });
  await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isLoading).toBeTruthy());
  await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBeTruthy());
});
```

The error says it has **Timed out in waitFor after 1000ms.** and that's a **Network error**

Any ideas how to fix this?

Also, it could be useful to know the interface:

```
type IUploadFieldRequest = {
  files: File[];
};
```

And the service:

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

import { requestConfig } from '@oam/shared/services';
import init, { Response } from '@oam/shared/utils/request-wrapper';

export const BASE_PATH =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? '/myurl/v1'
    : 'http://localhost:7999/v1';

export const licenseServiceAPI = <TRequest, TResponse = TRequest>(
  config?: AxiosRequestConfig
): [Response<TRequest, TResponse>, AxiosRequestConfig] => {
  const newConfig = requestConfig({
    baseURL: BASE_PATH,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      ...config?.headers
    },
    responseType: config?.responseType ? config?.responseType : undefined
  });
  return [init(newConfig), newConfig];
};

export default licenseServiceAPI;
```

Comment: Is your server live on `http://localhost:7999/v1`? Because that's the url that's gonna be used for your tests, because `process.env.NODE_ENV` equals to `'test'` when you run your tests.

Comment: And also, because of that reason (if your local server isn't live or not responding, etc), your tests become flaky. That's one of the reasons why you shouldn't use a real API in your tests, but instead mock your API calls.